# Given a distribution, what is the probability that x > 1 ?

Tags: probability

The question goes like this: given the distribution $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}3}\exp^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{3})^2}$ what is the probability that $x>1$ ?

What I did: Since this is a normal distribution with $\sigma=3,m=0$:   $prob(1<x<\infty)=\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ and after a lot of handwork I get the probability is $\approx0.84$. I do not know if this answer is correct, however, the reason I come here to ask is if there exists a more direct way to find out this probability or is it mandatory that I solve the integral?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The usual method of calculating these probabilities is by using the fact that if $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, thus 
$$
\frac{X- \mu}{\sigma}\sim N(0,1),
$$
and for the cumulative distribution of $N(0,1)$ there are the old fashioned-tables. Thus,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X >1) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \le 1) = 1 - \mathbb{P}((X-0)/3 \le 1/3) = 1 - \Phi \left(\frac{1}{3} \right).
$$
then you can use some software or the aforementioned tables of the standard normal distribution to find that $\Phi(1/3) = 0.63$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but how do you determine that P(X <= 1) is phi(1/3) ? Is this a rule I'm missing? Thank you again.

Comment: I've edited the answer

Comment: It is more clear this way, however do you think there is a way to do this analitically with integrals?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no closed-form [antiderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)